# How to upgrade go from 1.4 to 1.5 via homebrew

Tags: go, homebrew

I try brew upgrade go

it always show:

go 1.4.1 already installed

how can i upgrade go to 1.5?

Answer (score 60):

You should run `brew update` first, then run `brew upgrade` to upgrade all software installed by brew. Also you can run `brew upgrade go` to upgrade go only.

Answer (score 14):

`brew update` may warn you about multiple outdated libraries, so:

if you want to check **ALL outdated** libraries:

```
brew update
brew outdated
```

To upgrade a **SINGLE** library (like go in this case):

```
brew update
brew upgrade go
```

To upgrade **ALL** libraries:

```
brew update
brew upgrade
```

Answer (score 8):

Try running

```
brew update
brew upgrade

brew install go --cross-compile-common
```

`brew upgrade` might upgrade `go` alone without having to try to install it, after you run `brew update/upgrade` try running `go version` and see which version you have.

Comment: `brew upgrade` without `brew update` first won't pull down new versions of formulae, so the local Homebrew install won't know a newer Go verson is available to install.

Comment: @elithrar oh do I have them backwards

Comment: @Datsik what's `--cross-compile-common` for?

Comment: @RoyLee That was to allow the binaries to be used on other platforms as well. However, if I remember correctly, that's not required with some of the newer versions of Go now.

Comment: it does not take argument: `Error: invalid option: --cross-compile-common`